# Reference custom view in other project with custom font

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources, font-awesome

I am making WPF program. I have project where I have custom TextBlock control with custom font (font-awesome), I add this project in references of another project and add this custom control in this new project but the font is not shown. It is just square. I have set build action as Resource and Do not copy to output directory. What am I doing wrong? Both projects are class libraries. And I use them in other project (all these done for Prism)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the **Build Action** property of the font is set to **Resource** and that you reference the custom font using a pack URI as suggested here:

**Using custom font in WPF application:** http://geekswithblogs.net/Martinez/archive/2010/01/29/custom-font-in-wpf-application.aspx

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/Folder1/#Katana">Text</TextBlock>
```

Please refer to the link for more information.

Comment: I referred the link but it is very abstract. "pack://application:,,,/Folder1/#Katana"
what does application:,,, refers to? how to reference it from the very root solution folder?

Comment: If your font resource is located in the root folder of the project you remove the folder name: pack://application:,,,/#Katana. You can read more about pack URIs on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. If the resource is located in another assembly you should also include the name of this assembly in the pack URI, e.g.: pack://application:,,,/TheNameOfTheAssembly;component/#Katana.